# Imported function undefined when used with defaultProps

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a function called createTheme. Inside of createTheme there is a function called `createVariation` whose last argument is `buttonIteratee`.

If `buttonIteratee` is in the same file as `createTheme` I have no issue. But once I move it into another file (`button.tsx`) I get an error and `iteratee` becomes undefined:

`iteratee is not a function`

An important note might be, this only happens when I try to use `createTheme` to set the property as a default prop.

I'm wondering if this has something todo with *circular dependencies*?

createTheme.ts

```
// WHEN IMPORTED, IT DOESN'T.    
import { buttonIteratee } from '../Button/Button';

// WHEN DEFINED IN SAME FILE, IT WORKS.
const buttonIteratee = (theme, value) => ({
  backgroundColor: value,
});

export const createTheme = (theme: Theme): Theme => {
  const mergedTheme = merge(theme, defaultTheme);

  mergedTheme.buttonVariants = createVariation('colors', theme, buttonIteratee);

  return mergedTheme;
};
```

Button.tsx

```
Button.defaultProps = {
    ...
    theme: createTheme(defaultTheme),
};
```

Here is `createVariation` if that helps

```
export const createVariation = (
  path: keyof Theme,
  theme: Theme,
  iteratee: (theme: Theme, value: string) => CSSProperties,
): { [key: string]: CSSProperties } => {
  const properties = get(theme, path, {});
  const flattened: { [key: string]: string | number } = dotify(properties);
  return Object.entries(flattened).reduce((accumulator, [key, value]) => {
    const conversion: string = typeof value === 'number' ? `${value}px` : value;
    return { [key]: iteratee(theme, conversion), ...accumulator };
  }, {});
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to export buttonIteratee from Button.tsx in order to use it.